# $E[\overline{X}]$ of random samples from discrete uniform population

Tags: expected-value, uniform-distribution

Would  $E[\overline{X}]$ of random samples from discrete uniform population be $\frac{N+1}{2}$ (X goes from 1 to N)?

Comment: why wouldn't it? sounds like the mean of the underlying distribution is indeed $(N+1)/2$ and sample mean would need to approach that as the size of the sample increases...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If $X_i$ is sampled uniformly from $1,\dots,N$, then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_i] &= 1 \cdot \frac{1}{N} + 2\cdot \frac{1}{N} + \cdots + N\cdot \frac{1}{N}\\
&=\frac{1}{N}(1+2+\cdots+N)\\
&=\frac{1}{N}\cdot\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\\
&=\frac{N+1}{2}.
\end{align*}

So if $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are IID sampled uniformly from $1,\dots,N$ and $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}(X_1+\cdots+X_n)$, then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}]&=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{n}(X_1+\cdots+X_n)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{n}(\mathbb{E}[X_1]+\cdots+\mathbb{E}[X_n])\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\left(n\cdot \frac{N+1}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac{N+1}{2}.
\end{align*}